# when some value is set the same value must be reflected in datagridin wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datagrid

I am working on WPF using the MVVM architecture. 
My requirement is I have a datagrid which should be dynamically populated at each step whenever status is set.

For example :
suppose I am in a method called as `writeme()` which runs in background and there I set my status to "started", the datagrid must also show a column which says status and it should display "started " at the same time.

The method that I have applied is I have called a function whenever the value is set in the setter property and in that function I have bound that value to a `ObservableCollection` so that it can be displayed in the datagrid.

The problem is that I cannot display the same status for each and every level by level, I mean for each class that is the helper, until and all other internal classes.

Any kind of help would be great :)

Comment: Code samples would really help simplify your question ... please post what you've done so far

Comment: you want to show a single status or a status for each row?